# Android OpenGL compass

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-view, android-sensors

Can anyone help me with sample code for a compass needle that points in the direction where the phone is tilted?
I am trying to develop an application to rotate a bitmap in OpenGL from accelerometer values.

Comment: Do you *have* to use OpenGL? A custom View could do this where every time onDraw() is called the needle is moved in the appropriate direction.

Comment: thanks for replying .... A custom view is fine can u help me with a sample code...

Comment: @Graham Smith:I think it worked for me with the graphics part but i have no idea on calculating the angle of rotation from accelerometer values. Can you give me an outline on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so thanks to the comments above we do not have to use OpenGL, and while you could, I personally believe you can make life simpler by using a custom View.

Now in <strike>traditional</strike> standard StackOverFlow past time I am not going to give you code for this but extrmely large leg up. There is a thermometer example available here http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/.

**Why have I sent you here?**

It contains an example that renders a dial exceedingly close to a compass, with a few minor tweeks it could easily become a compass in terms of design. you will just need to remove the temperature related code and use the accelerometers instead.

It is a good intro to custom views and will show you how to get started.

I made a clock after following the tutorial just as another possibility to inspire you.